# How to have a program automatically close on runtime on Windows

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd.exe, windows-task-scheduler

I am needing to have a program that automatically closes if it is executed (aka it is ran, whether triggered by me or Windows itself) on Windows 10- the program cannot be uninstalled or disabled in any other way.
Could this be accomplished via a batch script using CMD, Powershell or the Task Scheduler? Please explain in as much detail as possible as I do not have expertise in those technologies (though I am tech savvy so feel free to use the "lingo"- just provide the steps on how to use the technologies).
I can provide additional context to the exact program needing to be closed, but I do not feel that is absolutely needed and this could definitely be applied in many contexts (i.e apply the same script with "insertexe.exe" if needed).
Basically I want to render this program unopenable without being able to/having to uninstall or deactive in any other way.

Comment: the big problem here is that you want it's state to be immutable to admins, and that is not at all easy to pull off. Antivirus is the only thing I've seen like it. it would have to run as localsystem, but someone with knowledge of psexec and admin access could always become localsystem if they so chose. I'd guess that developing a windows service would be the first part of the equation, but that is in itself non-trivial unless you are an experienced developer. In general programs just aren't supposed to run as you describe, except malware, like rootkits/bootkits.

Comment: It's not clear what the goal/purpose is. What problem are you solving?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the batch script below, you can modify the code `start %PROGRAM%` to `taskkill /im %PROGRAM%` to kill your program if it start.
https://github.com/lu-ko/utils-windows/blob/master/watchdog/watchdog.bat
You may also add this bat script to start-up
https://www.windowscentral.com/how-create-and-run-batch-file-windows-10

For example this batchscript will loop forever to check notepad.exe, if it is running terminate it. You can replace the fourth line of code to your application.exe.

```
@echo off
set TIMEOUT_RUNNING=20
set TIMEOUT_STOPPED=5
set "PROCESS_NAME=notepad.exe"
goto loop


:loop
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq %PROCESS_NAME%" /NH | find /I /N "%PROCESS_NAME%" >NUL

if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" (

 echo [%DATE% %TIME%] Process %PROCESS_NAME% is running - Kill
 taskkill /im "%PROCESS_NAME%"
 timeout %TIMEOUT_RUNNING%

) else (

 echo [%DATE% %TIME%] Process %PROCESS_NAME% is not running
 timeout %TIMEOUT_STOPPED%
)
goto loop
```

hope it helps

Comment: Will this script need to be set to run constantly? Ie if I make it a startup batch file will it need to be ran more than the startup? If I am correct, i can have task scheduler run it every 5 minutes or so and it would have the same effect?

Comment: I manually triggered the Batch script to run and ran a program testing it with an exe. It did not work. Any suggestions on errors I may have in the script? Particularly I am wondering about the second set line where I insert a name for .bat file. Should that be the bat file itself?

Comment: the error is on this line  taskkill /im "notepad.exe", I forget to change the name to  taskkill /im "%PROCESS_NAME%" sorry for that. This batch script will not stop unless you close it manually, so I suggess you to add it on your start up folder. If you want to hide the console window, take a look at this https://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_hideconsole.php

Comment: I keep getting the error "Testprogram.exe" is not running "Testprogram.exe". What is the difference between "PROCESS_Name=" and "PROGRAM="? Is the process Windows itself? Basically I want the script to kill the program when it runs (no matter what causes it to run but chiefly the user)

Answer (score 0):

> [Just try setting up your script as a service](https://www.bing.com/search?q=run%20powershel%20script%20as%20a%20service&form=ANNTH1&refig=2ae92441d2864db4a9e938d8884821b2&sp=-1&pq=run%20powershel%20script%20as%20a%20serv&sc=1-30&qs=n&sk=&cvid=2ae92441d2864db4a9e938d8884821b2)

, and set the group/local policy of your service to restart when stopped. Such as the SO approaches here:

> [How can I automatically restart a Windows service if it crashes?](https://serverfault.com/questions/48600/how-can-i-automatically-restart-a-windows-service-if-it-crashes)

```
SC failure w3svc reset= 432000  actions= restart/30000/restart/60000/run/60000
SC failure w3svc command= "MyBatchFile.cmd"
```

Again, as [Frank Thomas], if you need to stop any local admin, then this requires writing system-level code, not scripting code, to be as complete as possible. Admins are admins and by design can do whatever they want on their system.